# Динамический selet. Посылаю данные через ajax из select и не могу их считать в $_POST

Tags: ajax

Добрый день подскажите новичку. Пытаюсь реализовать динамический select
ес

```js
/*я понимаю что данные посылаются в какойто php файл и там идёт выборка из базы и возврат данных ктр подставятся на место <select id="user-list" >*/

function getIdCompany(val) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "#",
    data: {
      idCompany: val
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $("#user-list").html(data);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<select id="company-list" onchange="getIdCompany(this.value)">
  <option value="1">Компания 1</option>
  <option value="2">Компания 2</option>
  <option value="3">Компания 3</option>
  <option value="4">Компания 4</option>
</select>


<!--Сюда потом подгрузим выборку из базы-->
<select id="user-list">
  <option value="0">-Выберите пользователя-</option>
</select>


<!--хочу проверить что приходит в $_POST, а там пусто.-->
<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>
```

Comment: пост-запрос на другой файл вынесите например post.php

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю о такой фозможности делать запрос файлу на самого себя, как вы будете получать с самого себя, если там вводится html-контент, тогда вы в ответе аякса пришла не только переменная, но  и весь хтмл (теоретически).

Вот так работает, файл **index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>titile</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>

    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){

            $('#company-list').on('change', function(event) {
                console.log($(this).val());
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'post.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    data: {idCompany: $(this).val()},
                })
                .done(function() {
                    console.log("success");
                })
                .fail(function() {
                    console.log("error");
                });

            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <select id="company-list">
      <option value="1">Компания 1</option>
      <option value="2">Компания 2</option>
      <option value="3">Компания 3</option>
      <option value="4">Компания 4</option>
    </select>

</body>
</html>
```

**post.php**

```
<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>
```

Comment: Добрый день, спасибо за ответ, уже сам разобрался. Смотреть можно только через консоль. И данные действительно попадают в $_POST . но var_dump не сработает даже если вынести в отдельный файл. Страница же не обновляется .

Comment: @PeP1L для аякса не нужно обновление страницы.